# Using multiple file input fields in an HTML form

Tags: python, mysql, forms, file-upload, cgi

Is there some trick to using multiple file input fields in an html form? I tried using 3 of them so that 3 files can be uploaded at once but on the page that the form `POST`s to only the first input field actually uploads a file, the other 2 create files that are 0 bytes. I don't really want to use a file input with the 'multiple' attribute I'm trying to keep it as simple as possible

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data", action="MakeThread.py" method="POST">
<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="15728640" />
Your Name: <input type="text" name="name" /> <br />
Thread Subject: <input type="text" name="subject" size="50"/> <br />
Upload Image: <input type="file" name="image" accept="Image/gif,Image/jpeg,Image/png" /> (Optional) <br />
Upload Image: <input type="file" name="image2" accept="Image/gif,Image/jpeg,Image/png" /> (Optional) <br />
Upload Image: <input type="file" name="image3" accept="Image/gif,Image/jpeg,Image/png" /> (Optional) <br />
Body: <textarea name="body" rows="10" cols="100"></textarea> <br />
Keywords: <input type="text" name="keywords" size="50"/> Separate keywords with a comma (funny,pictures,...)<br />
<input type="hidden" name="topic" value="%s">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

here is the backend code, the 2nd and 3rd forms are commented out because i couldnt get it working but here it is...

```
...
image = args['image']
#image2 = args['image2']
#image3 = args['image3']
...
if fail == False:
    filesize = str(len(image.file.read()))
#    filesize2 = str(len(image2.file.read()))
#    filesize3 = str(len(image3.file.read()))
    image.file.seek(0)
#    image2.file.seek(0)
#    image3.file.seek(0)
    debug.append(filesize)
#    debug.append(filesize2)
#    debug.append(filesize3)
    if int(filesize) > 15728640:
        stop = True
        debug.append('Image 1 is too large')
#    if int(filesize2) > 15728640:
#        stop = True
#        debug.append('Image 2 is too large')
#    if int(filesize3) > 15728640:
#        stop = True
#        debug.append('Image 3 is too large')
    fn = os.path.basename(image.filename)
#    fn2 = os.path.basename(image2.filename)
#    fn3 = os.path.basename(image3.filename)
    fnl = fn.split('.')
    ext = str(fnl[-1])
#    fnl2 = fn.split('.')
#    ext2 = str(fnl2[-1])
#    fnl3 = fn.split('.')
#    ext3 = str(fnl3[-1])
    files = 0
    if ext.endswith(('gif', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'png')):
        fn = str(str(uuid.uuid4()) + '.' + ext)
        files = files + 1
    else:
        stop = True
        debug.append('Incorrect file type (Image 1)')
    """if ext2.endswith(('gif', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'png')):
        fn2 = str(str(uuid.uuid4()) + '.' + ext)
        files = files + 1
    else:
        stop = True
        debug.append('Incorrect file type (Image 2)')
    if ext3.endswith(('gif', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'png')):
        fn3 = str(str(uuid.uuid4()) + '.' + ext)
        files = files + 1
    else:
        stop = True
        debug.append('Incorrect file type (Image 3)')"""
    if stop == False:
#        if files == 3:
#            query = """INSERT INTO %s (topic_name, subject_name, poster_name, time, image, text, views, replies, keywords, image2, image3) VALUES (%%s, %%s, %%s, %%s, %%s, %%s, %%s, %%s, %%s, %%s, %%s)""" % ("Threads")
#            with con:
#                cur.execute(query, (topic, subject, postername, time, fn, body, 0, 0, formattedkeywords, fn2, fn3))
#                con.commit()
#                cur.execute('SELECT last_insert_id()')
#                pid = cur.fetchone()
#            with open("""uploadedimages/""" + fn, "wb") as fout:
#                in_chunks = iter(lambda: image.file.read(2 << 16), '')
#                fout.writelines(in_chunks)
#            with open("""uploadedimages/""" + fn2, "wb") as fout2:
#                in_chunks2 = iter(lambda: image2.file.read(2 << 16), '')
#                fout2.writelines(in_chunks)
#            with open("""uploadedimages/""" + fn3, "wb") as fout3:
#                in_chunks3 = iter(lambda: image3.file.read(2 << 16), '')
#                fout3.writelines(in_chunks)
#        elif files == 2:
#            query = """INSERT INTO %s (topic_name, subject_name, poster_name, time, image, text, views, replies, keywords, image2) VALUES (%%s, %%s, %%s, %%s, %%s, %%s, %%s, %%s, %%s, %%s)""" % ("Threads")
#            with con:
#                cur.execute(query, (topic, subject, postername, time, fn, body, 0, 0, formattedkeywords, fn2))
#                con.commit()
#                cur.execute('SELECT last_insert_id()')
#                pid = cur.fetchone()
#            with open("""uploadedimages/""" + fn, "wb") as fout:
#                in_chunks = iter(lambda: image.file.read(2 << 16), '')
#                fout.writelines(in_chunks)
#            with open("""uploadedimages/""" + fn2, "wb") as fout2:
#                in_chunks2 = iter(lambda: image2.file.read(2 << 16), '')
#                fout2.writelines(in_chunks)
```

sorry about the code being a little messy, im no pro by any means but I do try

Comment: Not only have you included loads of irrelevant commented-out code, you've completely failed to include the important information: what is `args`? And what are you running this on - a framework, raw CGI, what?

Comment: sorry, `args` is `args = cgi.FieldStorage()` and yes it is raw cgi and the commented out code is the code that pertains to the 2nd and 3rd file input fields in the form